# how to deploy and upload python app to CPanel?

Tags: python, django, cpanel, shared-hosting

Dears,
I'm trying to deploy a python web application on Cpanel hosting provider but I cannot determine the:

- Application startup file.
- Application Entry point.

Check attached screenshots (Cpanel required fields + app files), please need help and advice

[Cpanel required fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJG4y.png)

[Applications files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3FvE.png)

Answer (score 0):

leave both blank. They will be automatically generated.
Don't fill them.

Then edit passenger_wsgi.py like shown:

```
from <your project name>.wsgi import application
```

Comment: thank you very much for you reply, i already did that, then it generate a file called passenger_wsgi.py, i guess i need to modify that file in order to start my application