# Issues deploying Python Dash app using cPanel

Tags: python, error-handling, cpanel, plotly-dash, web-hosting

I am new to web hosting and am trying to deploy my [multi-page Python Dash app](https://dash.plotly.com/urls) via [cPanel](https://cpanel.net/). I have followed multiple tutorials and read a lot of documentation, including trying to apply approaches using similar Flask apps, but with no luck. I am able to run the app fine from the command line on my PC (typing `python app.py`); the issues just relate to deploying it.

Overview of the app directory structure:

```
- app.py
- data.csv #Read by the app.py file
- pages
   |-- page1.py
   |-- page2.py
   |-- page3.py
   |-- page4.py
   |-- page5.py
   |-- page6.py
   |-- page7.py
   |-- page8.py
- assets
   |-- image.png
   |-- favicon.ico
   |-- header.css
   |-- typography.css
- requirements.txt
- wsgi.py
```

## app.py (summary)

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import datetime as dt
#from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

app = Dash(__name__, use_pages=True, 
           external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
server = app.server
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
app.css.config.serve_locally = True

#Read data
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

navbar = dbc.Nav(
    [
    dbc.NavLink([
        html.Div(page["name"], className = "ms-2"), 
        ],
        href = page["path"], 
        active = "exact",
        #active = True,
        )
        for page in dash.page_registry.values()
    ], 
    vertical = False, 
    pills = True, 
    className = "bg-light"
    )

body_app = dbc.Container([
# user-selected data is stored in the memory --> can be shared between callbacks and pages
    dcc.Store(id = "store-data",
              data = [], 
              storage_type = "memory"),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            navbar #Allows users to navigate between the pages
            ])
        ]),
    
    ### Rest of the app style ###

        ], fluid = True)

app.layout = html.Div(id = 'parent', children = [body_app])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## requirements.txt

(some of these modules are required in other pages)

```
dash
dash_bootstrap_components
Dash
pandas
numpy
datetime
plotly
scikit-learn
dash-core-components
dash-html-components
dash-mantine-components
dash-table
```

## wsgi.py

This I have less experience with, but I have adapted an example I have found online:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/html/Dash/")
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/user/env/pweb/lib/python3.8/site-packages")
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/user/env/pweb")

from app import server as application
```

From the advice I have found in other forums asking asking similar questions, but I cannot see how to apply some of these steps in cPanel (such as when I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66218282/how-do-i-host-a-dash-app-on-an-apache-server)). Where I can, I just get a "We're sorry, but something went wrong" message on my app (such as when I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69279895/how-to-deploy-and-upload-python-app-to-cpanel)).

The closest I get to deploying it is when I follow this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=260eDcsUheE&t=2s) (for flask apps), but I get an "Incomplete response received from application" message on my app and the following errors in the passenger.log:

```
App 3219615 output: /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py:26: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
App 3219615 output:   import sys, os, re, imp, threading, signal, traceback, socket, select, struct, logging, errno
App 3219615 output: [ pid=3219615, time=2023-08-11 13:16:15,716 ]: WSGI application raised an exception!
App 3219615 output: Traceback (most recent call last):
App 3219615 output:   File "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 199, in main_loop
App 3219615 output:     socket_hijacked = self.process_request(env, input_stream, client)
App 3219615 output:   File "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 333, in process_request
App 3219615 output:     result = self.app(env, start_response)
App 3219615 output: TypeError: 'Dash' object is not callable
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated! I am also able to make changes to the app via cPanel's terminal within the app's environment, in case that is of any use.